# clear the controls and reset the form to its original state?

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says, how do i clear the controls and reset the form to its original state? I'm suppose to have it so when I click the button "Clear" it resets everything.  So I need something inside  the code below, but I'm not sure how to go about it, and everything I looked up wasn't clear.

```
 private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The rest of the code calculates grosspay, netpay, and a bunch of other tax deductions and display it on the form. So that is what I want to clear/reset on the form.

```
private void btnCalculatePay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double hourlyRate = Convert.ToDouble(txtHourlyRate.Text);
        double hoursWorked = Convert.ToDouble(txtHoursWorked.Text);

        double grossPay = hourlyRate * hoursWorked;

        double stateIncome = grossPay * 0.035;
        double federalIncome = grossPay * 0.15;
        double socialSecurity = grossPay * 0.062;
        double medicare = grossPay * .029;
        double netPay = grossPay - (stateIncome + federalIncome + socialSecurity + medicare);

        lblDisplay.Text = "Gross Pay: " + grossPay + "\nState Income Tax Deduction: " + stateIncome + "\nFederal Income Tax Deduction: " + federalIncome + "\nSocial Security Deduction: " + socialSecurity + "\nMedicare Deduction: " + medicare + "\nNet Pay: " + netPay;


    }
```

Comment: You appear to be looking for some magic that doesn't exist.  You clear a control exactly the same way as you populate it, e.g. by setting the `Text` of a `TextBox` and the `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` of a `ComboBox`.  Note that the `TextBox` also has a `Clear` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With clearing control if you mean clearing controls data then you can use controls `Text` property and set it to `string.Empty` like below. Again depending on the different controls you have in your form and not all controls do have a `Text` property.

```
 private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDisplay.Text = string.Empty;
        txtbox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```